# Red Hat 8: Is 'mod_ssl' missing in official repositories?

Tags: redhat, mod-ssl

I currently configure a Webserver with SSL certificate on a Red Hat 8 machine. I could not run properly `apachectl configtest` returning `Invalid command 'SSLCertificateFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

I found that the module `mod_ssl` is missing since I simply tried `yum install mod_ssl` which match no repository in Red Hat 8. Then I searched on https://pkgs.org/search/?q=mod_ssl where I could get the package. I thought `certwatch-mod_ssl-1.2-1.el8.x86_64.rpm` would do the job but it also requires the `mod_ssl` returning `nothing provides mod_ssl needed by certwatch-mod_ssl-1.2-1.el8.x86_64`

The option I have left is to install third party repositories for the SSL module from Raven Modular x86_64. I cannot imagine Red Hat 8 is not providing any own SSL module for the Apache server. This feels not correct to rely on third-party for such basic and crucial task.

Comment: For RHEL 8 mod_ssl is indeed (still) the name of the rpm package providing TLS/ SSL support and that should be available when your RedHat subscription is enabled and/or you have registered with your own satellite server. Check and confirm that you’re not using a restricted internal content view and/or are subscribed to the right channels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I found that the module `mod_ssl` is missing ... I simply tried `yum install mod_ssl` which match no repository in Red Hat 8.*

I am not able to reproduce your observation. In an almost out-of-box installation

```sh
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.8 (Ootpa)
```

the command `yum provides mod_ssl` just reports

```sh
mod_ssl-1:2.4.37-56.module+el8.8.0+18758+b3a9c8da.6.x86_64 : SSL/TLS module for the Apache HTTP Server
Repo        : rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
Matched from:
Provide    : mod_ssl = 1:2.4.37-56.module+el8.8.0+18758+b3a9c8da.6
```

The package seems to be available from within `rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms`. This indicates an issue somewhere else in your setup and configuration, specifically your subscription.

**How to proceed further?**

Check your Red Hat Subscription. In example

```yaml
~$ sudo subscription-manager status
+-------------------------------------------+
   System Status Details
+-------------------------------------------+
Overall Status: Current

System Purpose Status: Not Specified

~$ sudo subscription-manager list
+-------------------------------------------+
    Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+
Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64
Product ID:     479
Version:        8.8
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Subscribed
Status Details:
Starts:         01/01/2021
Ends:           01/01/2024
```

**Further Reading**

- [Subscription Manager `list` shows `Status Details: Not covered by a valid subscription`](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/653533)

Comment: I have 8.7 but this shouldn't be the reason. Provide command return error `No match found`. I have to double check my repositories

Comment: @Yann, check if your machine is registered in RHN.

Comment: machine was not registered